# Get Ext/Module Name of Form Element

Tags: magento

In admin configuration I have a section that has groups and fields. To one of those fields I'm doing some custom stuff via the `<frontend_model>` in `_getElementHtml()`

Is there a way to retrieve the module or extension name of the current extension within that function?

```
<sections>
    <extensionname translate="label" module="extensionname">
        <label>Extension Name</label>
```

sorry if my question isn't very clear... I know what I'm trying to do but stumbling in how to ask.

Comment: Perhaps if you show which area (via screenshot?) of the rendered page which you would like to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps me make my question more clear but here is the solution I finally came up with...

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element){
    $modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
    $modulesArray = (array)$modules;

    $module = '';
    foreach($modulesArray as $k => $v){
        if(strpos(strtolower($k), $this->getRequest()->getParam('section')) !== false){
            $module = $k;
        };
    }
```

essentially I was wanting to get the Extensions or "Modules" name so that later on in the code I could call this

`Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->modules->$module->version`

that way I wouldn't have to hard code in the extension or modules name it could be dynamic...

IF.... there is a better way of doing this please let me know as I am just hacking my way through this lol.